# ORMlite How to create a field of an entity type

Tags: android, inheritance, interface, field, ormlite

I use the ormlite in my android application. I created a java class with @DatabaseTable anntoation and appropriate fields with @DatabaseField annotation.

One of my fields is an entity type.

I need something like this:

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "math")
    public class Math implements Serializable
    {   ...
        @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
        private Math math;
        ... 
    }
```

but this generates errors:

```
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite does not know how to store class example.Math for field 'math'.  Use another class, custom  persister, or to serialize it use dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.<init>(FieldType.java:185)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.convertFieldConfigs(DatabaseTableConfig.java:236)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:101)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:151)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:126)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:117)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:919)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:919)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:72)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:277)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at .system.data.ormlitetest.DatabaseHelper.getMath(DatabaseHelper.java:152)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at .ui.access.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:65)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-31 15:05:49.203    2537-2537/ W/System.err? at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 15:05:49.233    2537-2537/ W/EGL_emulation? eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

When I set to my field: dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE it generate other errors:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "math")
public class Math implements Serializable
{   ...
   @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
   private Math math;
    ... 
}

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{/example.LoginActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): INTEGER data in nativeGetBlob
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): INTEGER data in nativeGetBlob
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:399)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.getBytes(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:161)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.SerializableType.resultToSqlArg(SerializableType.java:53)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.BaseFieldConverter.resultToJava(BaseFieldConverter.java:24)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:801)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:60)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:200)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:118)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:239)
    at example.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:68)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: PLz elaborate your question...what you actually want...so that we can help

Comment: Have a look at line 68 in example.LoginActivity.onCreate()